# Are we there yet?

Tags: anagram

> > > Quotations, but melt?

Have you found the answer yet?

Comment: battle mosquito nut

Comment: @LukeBickell If you are a battle nut against mosquitoes, I won't blame you... but that's not the answer ;) See the accepted answer if you give up

Comment: I know that's not the answer, I just found it funny :)

Comment: @LukeBickell Me too - that's why I was prepared with the "battle nut against mosquitoes" quip ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Not Quite, But Almost?

Comment: I had a feeling it was something along those lines, but I thought it was like "not yet"